# Specifying Compatibility Modes on a Per-Page Basis for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I have a strange issue with a Telerik RadWindow that only occurs in IE8. It works fine when I force the browser to use Document Mode: IE7 Standards. I am trying to specify IE7 compatibility mode on a Per-Page Basis for just one page in my site. using

```
<head>
   <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
</head>
```

According to the MSDN article this should do it, but it does not seem to work for me. Any other alternatives other than forcing a custom HTTP response header throughout the whole site. I only need to fix this one page?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817574.aspx

Comment: Weird...works on my site, and I'm doing it the same way.

Comment: thanks, getting mixed results from my IE8 browser? hopefully others don't get mixed results

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post a message about this as it doesn't appear to do anything either for me. I've just upgraded to IE8, and the only thing that breaks in my web app is the standard Microsoft Report Viewer control. Rather ironic that :-) I was expecting the Infragsitic NetAdvantage controls to break as they're quite heavy on CSS and JavaScript but they appear to be fine.

Therefore, I added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /`> line to my report viewer page but it doesn't seem to do anything. It still renders wrong unless I switch the entire site to compatability mode.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: I don't believe your error with the MS report viewer control is a standards mode issue.  Is the client machine with IE 8 that's having the report viewer error running Vista?

If yes, there is a bug that we're seeing related to IE 8 & Vista security that prevents the ActiveX report viewer control from working unless IE 8 is run as Administrator.

We have an open support ticket with MS to try to resolve the issue.  I'd love to find out more from you to see if our problem is infact the same, or if you have resolved your issues.

Comment: No, this is IE8 in Windows XP Professional. Did you ever hear back from your support ticket?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

also need to make sure it is not under other tags in the head.